# I'm getting the following error: ''IBI TimeframeU'' with no more information

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
src = input(defval = 'High/Low', title = "Source", options = ['High/Low', 'Close/Open'])
TimeframeU = input(defval = 'Auto', title ="Higher Time Frame", options = ['Auto', '15', '30', '60',         '120', '180', '240', '720', 'D', 'W', '2W', 'M', '3M', '6M', '12M'])
prd = input(defval = 10, title = "Period for Highest/Lowest Bars", minval = 1)
resistancecol = input(defval = color.red, title = "Resistance Color")
supportcol = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Support Color")
Transp = input(defval = 80, title = "Transparency for Zones", minval = 0, maxval = 100)
extendlines = input(defval = false, title = "Extend Lines")

Timeframe = timeframe.period
if TimeframeU == 'Auto'
    Timeframe := timeframe.period == '1' ? '15' : 
       timeframe.period == '3' ? '15' :
       timeframe.period == '5' ? '60' : 
       timeframe.period == '15' ? '60' : 
       timeframe.period == '30' ? '120' : 
       timeframe.period == '45' ? '120' : 
       timeframe.period == '60' ? '240' : 
       timeframe.period == '120' ? 'D' : 
       timeframe.period == '180' ? 'D' : 
       timeframe.period == '240' ? 'D' : 
       timeframe.period == 'D' ? 'W' :
       timeframe.period == 'W' ? 'M' :
       '12M'
else
    Timeframe := TimeframeU
```

And the problem I get is the following:

```
20:07:03        |B|TimeframeU
```

I renamed the part and anything but I have no more ideas how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to replicate this error. I updated the inputs to correct syntax and seems to compile fine. I put a label on the chart to test your 'auto' time frame as well.

[15 Minute Chart Image with label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jOhp.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator('test', overlay = true)
src = input.string(defval = 'High/Low', title = "Source", options = ['High/Low', 'Close/Open']) 
TimeframeU = input.string(defval = 'Auto', title ="Higher Time Frame", options = ['Auto', '15', '30', '60', '120', '180', '240', '720', 'D', 'W', '2W', 'M', '3M', '6M', '12M']) 
prd = input.int(defval = 10, title = "Period for Highest/Lowest Bars", minval = 1) 
resistancecol = input.color(defval = color.red, title = "Resistance Color") 
supportcol = input.color(defval = color.lime, title = "Support Color") 
Transp = input.int(defval = 80, title = "Transparency for Zones", minval = 0, maxval = 100) 
extendlines = input.bool(defval = false, title = "Extend Lines")

Timeframe = timeframe.period
if TimeframeU == 'Auto'
    Timeframe := timeframe.period == '1' ? '15' : 
       timeframe.period == '3' ? '15' :
       timeframe.period == '5' ? '60' : 
       timeframe.period == '15' ? '60' : 
       timeframe.period == '30' ? '120' : 
       timeframe.period == '45' ? '120' : 
       timeframe.period == '60' ? '240' : 
       timeframe.period == '120' ? 'D' : 
       timeframe.period == '180' ? 'D' : 
       timeframe.period == '240' ? 'D' : 
       timeframe.period == 'D' ? 'W' :
       timeframe.period == 'W' ? 'M' :
       '12M'
else
    Timeframe := TimeframeU

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high, 'Current TimeFrame: ' + str.tostring(timeframe.period) + '\n TimeFrameU: ' + str.tostring(Timeframe), color = color.lime)
```